# Understanding Spring annotation DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

> @Repository @Service  @Controller
>   @Component

-->only use for spring managed bean (no need weaving) 
-->@repository, @Service @controller is actually a @Component , just naming easier for programmer to understand

```
@Configurable
```

--->used for non spring managed bean (use with weaving)

```
@Autowired
```

--> use for DI for both cases above

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All but @Configurable are correct.  From the Spring javadocs:

> public @interface Configurable
>   Marks a class as being eligible for Spring-driven configuration.  Typically used with the AspectJ AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.

Answer (score 1):

Spring annotations draws different purposes. As you know Spring heavily uses proxies in order to provide its funcionality. **But this funcionality depends on the target annotation**.

So when you put

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    public void saveUser(User user) {
        // logic goes here
    }

}
```

You are saying

> Spring, proxy my UserRepositoryImpl and if it throws any database exception, caught it and re-throw it as a DataAccessException, a generic Spring database exception

And so on...

regards,